# Cycle PDF Pages in WPF WebView2

Tags: wpf, webview2

I have created a WPF + WebView2 sample project modeled after this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf). Instead of setting `webView2.Source` equal to some URI I set it to "test.pdf". From there I am wondering how to navigate between the pages programmatically? I cannot find any API or documentation that shows how to do something like `pdf.GetNextPage()` or `pdf.OpenPage(int num)`. I know Adobe used to let you access the pages via URI like "test.pdf#page=2" but I can't find anything on this for WebView2. Any help is appreciated.

```xml
<Window x:Class="AutoMediaDisplay.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:localNamespace"
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="PDF Viewer" Height="450" Width="800">

    <DockPanel>
        <wv2:WebView2 Name = "webView"
                      Source = "test.pdf"
            />
    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to WebView2, but applies generally to the PDF viewer in the Edge browser. It looks like appending a URI fragment of the form `page={N}` to the end of a PDF URI will navigate you within the PDF document to that page. I don't find this documented in the Edge browser PDF reader documentation.

However, if you're already on the URI for the PDF, just navigating to the same URI but with a new URI fragment doesn't seem to navigate within the document. Instead if I navigate from a PDF URI to the same PDF URI but with a different URI fragment, then I had to force a page reload to be navigated appropriately within the PDF document. I found this to be the case both in the browser and additionally in WebView2.

Comment: For example `webView.Source = new Uri("file:///D:/file-name.pdf#page=22");`

Comment: How did you find out about the `page=` parameter? Are there others?